# Insert newline print statement into (nested)? for loop?

Tags: python, for-loop, matrix

I'm trying to print a matrix with user assigned variable for the length and width, but have used manual assignment for easier reading.  Right now my output doesn't include any new lines, but that is what I'm attempting to do.

```
def matrix(rows,cols):
    grid = [[0 for i in range(cols)] for i in range(rows)]
    return grid

rows = 5
cols = 5
print(matrix(rows,cols))
```

Is it possible to insert a print("\n") statement into the for statement to properly print out the matrix.  Currently the output is as follows:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Desired output:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: I would just like to point out that inserting a print statement in your for loop would be a bad idea, even if you could do that. Its often a good idea to have a clear separation between your data (the matrix) and your presentation layer (printing, user interface, stc).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That happens to be the exact behaviour of [pprint](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pprint.html).

```
from pprint import pprint

def matrix(rows,cols):
    grid = [[0 for i in range(cols)] for i in range(rows)]
    return grid

rows = 5
cols = 5
pprint(matrix(rows,cols))
```

Comment: I made the changes you suggested, I'm receiving a "unexpected EOF while parsing" error.  Reading up on the link you left.

Comment: I was missing a closing ) on the call to pprint(). Try adding it :)

Comment: Ah yes, ha.  I tend to miss the litte things sometimes, appreciate the follow up.

Answer (score 0):

pprint doing what you need is nice, but shouldn't you be using a class for your matrix type?  Using a naked list of lists may bite you later.